# Why does @ApiModelProperty "name" attribute has no effect?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

In my spring boot app, I have a DTO object with a nested list of DTO objects.
class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ApiModel(value = "contact")
public class ContactDTO {
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "id", example = "1", hidden = true)
  private Long id;

  @ApiModelProperty(value = "first name", example = "John")
  private String firstName;

  @ApiModelProperty(value = "last name", example = "Doe")
  private String lastName;

  @Builder.Default
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "list of phone numbers", name = "phonenumbers")
  List<PhoneNumberDTO> phoneNumberDTOList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

the swagger example value for a post request:

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "phoneNumberDTOList": [
    {
      "label": "Company",
      "number": "put number here"
    }
  ]
}
```

I thought the `name = ...` property in `@ApiModelProperty` overwrites the variable name `phoneNumberDTOList`, but that doesn't work :(

**I use springfox-swagger 2.9.2**

```
  implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2'
  implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check out this issue:

[@ApiModelProperty "name" attribute has no effect](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1289)

- > We don't want ever to have a case where the serialization model is different from whats being documented.
- > Actually the existence of `@ApiModelProperty` is explained by the fact that we want to use the same annotations that **swagger-core** uses. However we take the philosophy of using the annotations just to supplement documentation. If for e.g. you've annotated your models with `@JsonProperty` etc we don't want to duplicate that using `@ApiModelProperty` as it is very easy to get out of sync.

There is a workaround with `@JsonProperty` annotation:

```
...

@JsonProperty("phonenumbers")
@ApiModelProperty(value = "list of phone numbers")
List<PhoneNumberDTO> phoneNumberDTOList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: wow this issue is from November 2016... thanks to you - that works with `@JsonProperty`

Comment: @JsonProperty will disappear the column name on the SwaggerUI, is there any other option?